# Derive the type of an array in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a type that's defined in a third party library. Let's say its shape is:

```
type Foo = {
  id: string
  results: Array<{ bar: string }>
}
```

Is there a way to derive the type `{ bar: string }`?

I'd like to use it like so:

```
type Baz = /* derived type */

const baz: Baz = { bar: 'abc' }
```

I was looking at [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)... but couldn't figure out how to target that part of the type definition.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays indexed by `number` give you the member type of the array, since arrays *are* indexed by integers.

```
type Foo = {
  id: string
  results: Array<{ bar: string }>
}

type Baz = Foo['results'][number]
const baz: Baz = { bar: 'abc' }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKBLAJgLigGdgAnbAOwHNMpSIiBXAG2CMIEFTSBDEAHlRQARj1KES5alAC+APnQz06UJCgAhHgC9ksBAG0A5PSasihgLr6KjALbCIpC+gDGcCiRHbCmnSiGi4lCGPMIuhrJAA)

Comment: Woah - this is clever. And this works because the types of _all_ indexes are the same? (i.e., if the array were `[1, 'a', {foo: 'bar'}]` this wouldn't work? Or...?

Comment: It'll work fine, you'd just get `1 | 'a' | { foo: 'bar' }` as the type. So it's less valuable for [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple). But for unbounded arrays of homogenous member types, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Got some help from a TS wizard. This is a working solution:

```
type Foo = {
  id: string
  results: Array<{bar: string}>
}

type ElementsOf<T extends unknown[]> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer E> ? E : never;

// type Baz = { bar: string; } 
type Baz = ElementsOf<Foo["results"]>;
```

Would *love* if someone could help explain the ternary though.

Comment: This says that if if `T` is a subtype of a readonly array, infer the member value from the array and return it. If `T` is not a read only array, then return `never`, indicating that inferring the member type failed. Seems like a lot of effort though.

Comment: @AlexWayne - agreed. This seems to be a common pattern that I've seen though.

Comment: @AlexWayne how can `T` not be a readonly array?  Keep in mind that `readonly any[]` is *wider* than `any[]` ([observe](https://tsplay.dev/w8KaPW)).  Yeah, the naming is not great; essentially regular arrays should be called `ReadableAndWritableArray` and "readonly array" should be `ReadableArray`, and then it might seem less crazy that every `ReadableAndWritableArray` is also a `ReadableArray`.

Comment: Of course you were just explaining the conditional type, which is indeed a lot of effort for the equivalent of `T[number]`.

Comment: @jcalz TIL, but now that I think about that actually makes sense. Yeah this is one of those where you need the conditional type for the infer, and the negative clause will never be taken.